# Email no Duplication and Fullname with middlename (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, codeigniter, validation

im trying to make a enrollment system in the school and i need help
not to duplicate the emails and fullname with middlename, but if the name and lastname is the same its ok to add but with the middlename will not continue to add the student. still the same process when i update the student

```
function student($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    if ($param1 == 'create') {
        $data['name']        = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['mname']       = $this->input->post('mname');
        $data['lastname']    = $this->input->post('lastname');
        $data['birthday']    = $this->input->post('birthday');
        $data['sex']         = $this->input->post('sex');
        $data['address']     = $this->input->post('address');
        $data['phone']       = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['email']       = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password']    = md5($this->input->post('password')); 
        $data['father_name'] = $this->input->post('father_name');
        $data['mother_name'] = $this->input->post('mother_name');
        $data['class_id']    = $this->input->post('class_id');
        $data['roll']        = $this->input->post('roll');
        $this->db->insert('student', $data);
        $student_id = mysql_insert_id();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/student_image/' . $student_id . '.jpg');
        $this->email_model->account_opening_email('student', $data['email']); //SEND EMAIL ACCOUNT OPENING EMAIL
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('add_student_success'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student/' . $data['class_id'], 'refresh');
    }
    if ($param2 == 'do_update') {
        $data['name']        = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['mname']       = $this->input->post('mname');
        $data['lastname']    = $this->input->post('lastname');
        $data['birthday']    = $this->input->post('birthday');
        $data['sex']         = $this->input->post('sex');
        $data['address']     = $this->input->post('address');
        $data['phone']       = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['email']       = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password']    = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        $data['father_name'] = $this->input->post('father_name');
        $data['mother_name'] = $this->input->post('mother_name');
        $data['class_id']    = $this->input->post('class_id');
        $data['roll']        = $this->input->post('roll');

        $this->db->where('student_id', $param3);
        $this->db->update('student', $data);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/student_image/' . $param3 . '.jpg');
        $this->crud_model->clear_cache();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('edit_student_success'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student/' . $param1, 'refresh');
    } else if ($param2 == 'edit') {
        $page_data['edit_data'] = $this->db->get_where('student', array(
            'student_id' => $param3
        ))->result_array();
    } else if ($param2 == 'personal_profile') {
        $page_data['personal_profile']   = true;
        $page_data['current_student_id'] = $param3;
    } else if ($param2 == 'academic_result') {
        $page_data['academic_result']    = true;
        $page_data['current_student_id'] = $param3;
    }
```

Comment: have a look at `is_unique` validation rules for the email and for the firstname and last name, you can create a validation callback for that., you might want to validate first before throwing it in the model.

Comment: hi @TomeӾsanS can you help me with that? i want to learn about this im so newbie in programming i dont know what to do..